How to reformulate optimization under equality constraint as a minimax optimization problem?
Suppose I have the following optimization under equality constraint: $\max_x f(x)$ subject to $h(x)=0$.
How can I reformulate it as a minimax optimization problem in the sense of $\min_t \max_s Q(s,t)$? It would be great if you could provide the details and intuition when deriving the reformulation.
